# Python: Efficient looping in dataframe to find duplicates for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, duplicates

I am using python and I want to go through a dataset and highlight the most used locations.

This is my dataset (but with 300,000+ records):

```
Longitude   Latitude
14.28586    48.3069
14.28577    48.30687
14.28555    48.30678
14.28541    48.30673
```

First I add a density column:

```
df['Density'] = 0
```

And this is the code that I am using to increase the density value for each record:

```
for index in range(0,len(df)):
    for index2 in range(index + 1, len(df)):
        if df['Longitude'].loc[index] == df['Longitude'].loc[index2] and df['Latitude'].loc[index] == df['Latitude'].loc[index2]:
            df['Density'].loc[index] += 1
            df['Density'].loc[index2] += 1
            print("match")
    print(str(index) + "/" + str(len(df)))
```

The code above is simply iterating through the dataframe, comparing the first record against all the other records in the dataset (inner loop) and when a match is found both of their density values are incremented.

I want to find the Longitudes and Latitudes that match and increase their density value.

The code is obviously very slow and I am sure that Python will have a cool technique for doing something like this, any ideas?

Comment: can you explain the logic what your code is doing?

Comment: I have updated my question to try and make that clearer

Comment: If a (lat,lon) pair appears 2 times, the `Duplicated` column should be `1` for both rows. Can we generalize that to if a pair appears `N` times in the dataset, their `Duplicated` column should equal `N-1`

Comment: That would also work, do you have any suggestion on how to code that efficiently?

Comment: This wouldnt look for paired duplicates though would it? just duplicates on a single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated`, `groupby`, `transform` & `sum` to achieve this:

Lets create a sample dataset that actually has duplicates

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'lon': [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]})
```

First flag the duplicate rows based on `lat` & `lon`, & apply the transform to create a new column

```
df['is_dup'] = df[['lat', 'lon']].duplicated()
df['dups'] = df.groupby(['lat','lon']).is_dup.transform(np.sum)
# df outputs:
df['is_dup'] = df[['lat', 'lon']].duplicated()
df['dups'] = df.groupby(['lat','lon']).is_dup.transform(np.sum)
```

Comment: That has done it thank you. I didnt know about some of these python techniques.